# R: How to access the elements of a list in a loop

Tags: r, list

I have two files. One file contains information about Genes. It looks like this.

```
Query|       Gene |  Desc
APECO1_1380 | fldA   | flavodoxin FldA
APECO1_2545 | fpr    |ferredoxin-NADP reductase
APECO1_3632  |fldB   | flavodoxin FldB
APECO1_1465  |fepA   | ferrienterobactin receptor
APECO1_4396 | cirA   | colicin I receptor
```

The second files contains a list of GeneCodes.

```
APECO1_1380
APECO1_2545
APECO1_3632
```

I'm trying to extract Gene information from file 1 for the Gene codes in File 2. Below is the code I'm using.

```
#Files with gene data for GeneCodes(File 1)     
dataT = read.csv("D://SBMLexploration/Genes/genenames.csv",header = TRUE)

#Has the second type of files (files with the GeneCode) - File 2

fileList = list.files("D://SBMLexploration/Genes/Test1")

df = data.frame(MonkCode = character(), GeneName = character(), 
                Description = character(), stringsAsFactors = F)

for(i in 1:length(fileList))
{
  currentGenes = read.csv(fileList[i],header = T)

  for(j in 1:nrow(currentGenes))
  {
    curentRow = subset(dataT,dataT$Query == currentGenes[j,1])

    df<-rbind(df,data.frame(MonkCode = currentRow$Query,
                            GeneName = currentRow$Gene,
                            Description = currentRow$Desc))
  }
  write.table(df,fileName,sep=",",row.names = F)
  df = NULL

}
```

My problem is when I provide a GenCode as `currentGenes[j,1]` the query returns 0 rows. But when I give the Code as a string (with in `APECO1_1465`) it returns the record. The issue is with the way I'm referring to the list. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: `as.character(currentGenes[j,1])` ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but fyi you can just type `Query` instead of `dataT$Query` inside of `subset`.

Comment: It worked with as.character(). Thank you very much. I'm a beginner in R and the lists are very difficult to deal with!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply transform `currentGenes[j,1]` into a string using `as.character()`.

I.e.`as.character(currentGenes[j,1])`

Answer (score 1):

R's syntax is not it's strong point and can lead to lots of frustrating errors like the one you describe. At the risk of starting a flamewar, let me suggest the `dplyr` library and show an alternative, dplyr-based solution below.

```
library(dplyr)

#load your reference data and register your gene files
dataT = read.csv("D://SBMLexploration/Genes/genenames.csv",header = TRUE)
fileList = list.files("D://SBMLexploration/Genes/Test1")

# load genes from a file and output refencedata
processdata <- function(ref_df, filename){

  genes = read.csv(filename,header = T, col.names = c("genes"))

  refdf %>% 
    filter(Query %in% genes$genes) %>%
    mutate(MonkCode = Query, 
           GeneName = Gene, 
           Description = Desc) %>%
    select(MonkCode,GeneName,Description) %>%
    write.table(file=paste0(filename,"_hits.txt"))
}

#apply your function to each file
Map(processdata,fileList)
```

Comment: This look like a more neat solution. Thank you